# Can simplify composite generics? How to avoid [T1 with T2]?

Tags: scala, generics

Consider

```
trait E[C] {
  type CONTEXT = C
  def doIt(c:CONTEXT): Unit = {}
}

// My doIt method takes a C
case class ESimple[C]() extends E[C] 

// ECompound's doIt method must satisfy the requirements of both
// a's and b's doIt parameters.
case class ECompound[C1,C2](a:E[C1],b:E[C2]) extends E[C1 with C2] {
  override def doIt(c: CONTEXT): Unit = {
    a.doIt(c)
    b.doIt(c)
  }
}
```

... and so:

```
case class Context 
val context = Context()

val a:E[Context] = ESimple[Context]()
val b:E[Context] = ESimple[Context]()
val c:E[Context] = ECompound(a,b)  // type mismatch
```

This fails because

```
val c:E[Context with Context] = ECompound(a,b)  // type not mismatched
```

is the reported type of ECompound(a,b). So, it is possible to resolve this? ECompound(a,b).doIt really should only require a "Context", it is  not simplified from "Context with Context"

I realize I can solve this by changing "... extends E[C1 with C2]" to extends[C1], but at the cost of requiring C1==C2, which I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... this is embarrassing.

Turns out that I was compiling to scala 2.10. Using 2.11.8, my original worked out fine, with one small change to E:

```
trait E[-C] {  // Added -C
  def doIt(c: C): Unit = {}
  def asE: E[C] = this // see below
}

case class ESimple[C]() extends E[C]

//case class ECompound[C1, C2, CC <: C1 with C2](a: E[C1], b: E[C2]) extends E[CC] {
//case class ECompound[CC, C1 >: CC, C2 >: CC](a:E[C1],b:E[C2]) extends E[CC] {
case class ECompound[C1, C2](a: E[C1], b: E[C2]) extends E[C1 with C2] {
  override def doIt(c: C1 with C2): Unit = {
    a.doIt(c)
    b.doIt(c)
  }
}

trait Context1
trait Context2

val e1: E[Context1] = ESimple[Context1]()
val e2: E[Context2] = ESimple[Context2]()

val cc11: E[Context1] = ECompound(e1, e1)
val cc12: E[Context1 with Context2] = ECompound(e1, e2)

case class X()

cc12.doIt(new X with Context1 with Context2)
```

However, the ugly part about this is:

```
def compileTimeType[T](x: T)(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]) = tag.tpe

val a = ECompound(e1, e1)
val b = ECompound(a, a)
val c = ECompound(b, b)
println( compileTimeType( c.asE ) )
```

gives:

```
com.example.E[com.example.Context1
    with com.example.Context1
    with com.example.Context1
    with com.example.Context1
    with com.example.Context1
    with com.example.Context1
    with com.example.Context1
    with com.example.Context1]
```

which (without loss in generality), can be simplified to:

```
com.example.E[com.example.Context1]
```

but is not. Sure makes for some nasty compiler errors...

If you can avoid this mess, this answer is yours.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to define `ECompound` as:

```
 case class ECompound[C1,C2, CC <: C1 with C2](a:E[C1],b:E[C2]) extends E[CC]
```

The drawback is that if you don't specify `CC` explicitly it will be inferred as `Nothing`, i.e.:

```
val c: E[Context] =
  ECompound(ESimple[Context](), ESimple[Context]()) // works

val c1: E[Context with Context1] =
  ECompound(ESimple[Context](), ESimple[Context1]()) // works

val c2 =
  ECompound(ESimple[Context](), ESimple[Context1]()) 
  // works, but inferred type is ECompound[Context,Context1,Nothing]
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider defining `ECompound` as:

```
case class ECompound[CC, C1 >: CC, C2 >: CC](a:E[C1],b:E[C2]) extends E[CC] {
  override def doIt(c: CONTEXT): Unit = {
    a.doIt(c)
    b.doIt(c)
  }
}
```